# Angular JS with jQuery Issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, javascript-framework

I am using Angular JS - v1.0.3 with jQuery - 1.7.2 in my Ruby on Rails application.

I am having live and bind events in my JS files. The JS bindings are not happening properly.

```
jQuery(id).live("click", function(){ alert('test');});
```

If i define the event again in my chrome console, even then the binding does not happen. But if i do

```
jQuery(id).click(function(){ alert('test');});
```

Then the binding happens. Can anyone help me with what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method .live() was deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 use .on() instead.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks Carlos! I tried with .on() as well but i get same issue.

Comment: Probably you have another event attached to the element that is stopping the event chain. Inspect the onclick events attached to the element by using jQuery(element).data("events").click